# How to connect to azure cosmos db account in a c# code without using primary key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have been trying to connect to Azure Cosmos DB account. The actual aim is to get the keys for testing purposes. So I cannot use keys to login into the cosmos DB account.

I found approaches online which are using the primary key to login but that is not my aim. Further, I found this approach on stack overflow using fluent SDK but it is not working for me.
[Getting azure cosmos DB key programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248538/getting-resetting-azure-cosmos-db-master-keys-programmatically)

I found another way of certificate-based authentication here-[Certificate Based authentication for cosmos db](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/certificate-based-authentication)

I came across this command to fetch the primary key but the issue is that I am unable to connect to azure cosmos DB account through c# code which is not allowing me to fetch keys.

```
var cosmosPrimaryKey = _accountCosmosDBProvider.GetPrimaryKey(rgName, accountName, CancellationToken.None);
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to proceed for the same?

Comment: Could you please tell me your error message?

Comment: This is the error message when I am trying to login through Certificate using sdk.
"Client assertion contains invalid signature". 
further these are the commands that I am using

var azure=Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
var cosmosaccount=azure.CosmosDbAccounts.GetByResourceGroup(rgname, accountName);
var PrimaryKey=cosmosaccount.ListKeys.PrimaryMasterKey();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the information, I do a test on my side. We can use the following steps to get the private key.

1. Register an Azure AD application
   [image]
   [image]
2. Create the certificate-based credential

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject "CN=sampleAppCert" -KeySpec KeyExchange -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10) -NotBefore (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)


$bin = $cert.RawData
$base64Value = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bin)

Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "<your tenant id>"
$app=Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId < the object id of the app you create>
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId 77bfe399-38db-4ce5-85b1-c79ef0ed5e5b -CustomKeyIdentifier "key12" -Value $base64Value -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -EndDate $cert.NotAfter
```

3. Configure your Azure Cosmos account to use the new identity
   [image]
4. Code

```
            # get the certificate
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "sampleAppCert", false);
            cert = signingCert.OfType<X509Certificate2>().OrderByDescending(c => c.NotBefore).FirstOrDefault();
            store.Close();

            # get the Azure CosmosDB Primary Master Key
            string tenantId = "";
            string clientId = "the Azure AD application appid";
            string subscriptionId = "the subscription id";
            string rgName = "";
            string accountName = "";
            var creds = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                clientId,
                cert,
                tenantId,
                AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud
                );

            var azure = Azure.Configure()
                             .Authenticate(creds)
                             .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

            var keys = azure.CosmosDBAccounts.ListKeys(rgName, accountName);
            Console.WriteLine(keys.PrimaryMasterKey);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @JimXu . This approach works fine for me.